# How to access database in asp.net on Lan (IIS Server)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have an asp.net website that runs on my localhost and creates records on Sql server 2008 on my machine. When i try to run this website over LAN (from an other pc) the pages that don’t have any relation with the database run. 
The other pages that shows records don’t run.
 Any solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of authentication are you using for your SQL database?

Comment: what is "don't run"? do you get an exception, what is it?

Comment: @AndreiD.. I am using Windows Authentication in the sql server

Comment: @raja.. i am getting no exceptions. The records from the database doesn't get displayed.

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure your connection string is correctly pointing to the SQL Server with the right credentials.
2. Ensure the SQL server can be connected remotely by opening up port 1433, 1434 etc in the Firewall. (else you'll get an error like 'a network-related or instance specific error...')

[Why am I getting "Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error)